# I want to use javascript for loop variable dynamic in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

**how can use multiple for loop variable in jsp expression tag**

```
<script>
for(var a=0;a<dir.length;a++){
   document.getElementById(a).innerHTML = dir[a];
}
for(var r=0;r<dir.length;r++){
   document.getElementById(r).innerHTML = dir[r];
}
</script>
```

**Here, I want used**

```
 <%for(int i=0;i<imei_no.length;i++){%>
    <span id = "<%=a>"/>//how can assign variable a for dynamic
    <span id = "<%=r>"/>//how can assign variable r for dynamic
    <%}%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% for(int i=0;i<imei_no.length();i++){
          out.print("<span id = \"" + a + "\"/>");
          out.print("<span id = \"" + r + "\"/>");
    }%>
```

Comment: try to add some description to your answer